# Exception when trying to get reference to MongoDB collections with .Net Core 3.0 (MongoDB.Driver 2.8.0)

Tags: c#, mongodb, .net-core

My Environment:

Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms (3.0.0-preview5.19224.8)

MongoDB.Driver (2.8.0)

[image]

My problem:

Before updating the version of "Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms" the following code worked perfectly:

```
//Collection of resales
public IMongoCollection<Revenda> CollRevendas;

public BaseRepository(IConfiguration config)
{
    try
    {
        // Location of the database, configured in the "appsettings.json" file
        var client = new MongoClient(config.GetConnectionString("Config.api.mstiDFE"));

        // Name of the database
        Database = client.GetDatabase("api_mstiDFE_II");

        // Get the reference for the collection "Resales"
        CollRevendas = Database.GetCollection<Revenda>("Revendas");

    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }

}
```

After updating, when attempting to execute the "CollRevendas = Database.GetCollection("Revendas");" statement, the following exception is thrown:

{"The type initializer for 'MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonClassMap' threw an exception."}

[image]

With the following stack trace:

```
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonClassMap' threw an exception. ---> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: type
at System.Reflection.IntrospectionExtensions.GetTypeInfo(Type type)
at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonClassMap..cctor()
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonClassMap.LookupClassMap(Type classType)
at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonClassMapSerializationProvider.GetSerializer(Type type, IBsonSerializerRegistry serializerRegistry)
at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonSerializerRegistry.CreateSerializer(Type type)
at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonSerializerRegistry.GetSerializer[T]()
at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1..ctor(IMongoDatabase database, CollectionNamespace collectionNamespace, MongoCollectionSettings settings, ICluster cluster, IOperationExecutor operationExecutor)
at MongoDB.Driver.MongoDatabaseImpl.GetCollection[TDocument](String name, MongoCollectionSettings settings)
at api.mstiDFE.Infra.Repositories.BaseRepository..ctor(IConfiguration config) in C:\Users\Source\Workspace\api.mstiDFE\api.mstiDFE\Infra\Repositories\BaseRepository.cs:line 27
```

Unfortunately I can not downgrade the "Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms". So any hint will be very welcome.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Version 2.8.1 of the MongoDB Driver for C # was released yesterday (05-15-19).
Soon after asking this question, I obtained the information in the following link:

[CSHARP-2595: Fix initialization on .NET Core 3.0 preview 4.](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/pull/372)

After upgrading to version 2.8.1, the issue was resolved.

So I'll leave the question here as it can serve other people with the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

The same issue was happening in 2.9.0-beta1 also but updating to 2.9.0-beta2 fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score -1):

You need to install MongoDB.Bson package also.
`<PackageReference Include="MongoDB.Bson" Version="2.11.4" />`

It worked for me.